# How to load multiple images in a numpy array ?

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing

How to load pixels of multiple images in a directory in a numpy array . I have loaded a single image in a numpy array . But can not figure out how to load multiple images from a directory . Here what i have done so far

```
image = Image.open('bn4.bmp')
nparray=np.array(image)
```

This loads a 32*32 matrices . I want to load 100 of the images in a numpy array . I want to make 100*32*32 size numpy array . How can i do that ? I know that the structure would look something like this

```
for filename in listdir("BengaliBMPConvert"):
  if filename.endswith(".bmp"):
       -----------------
  else:
       continue
```

But can not find out how to load the images in numpy array

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### Getting a list of BMP files

To get a list of BMP files from the directory `BengaliBMPConvert`, use:

```
import glob
filelist = glob.glob('BengaliBMPConvert/*.bmp')
```

On the other hand, if you know the file names already, just put them in a sequence:

```
filelist = 'file1.bmp', 'file2.bmp', 'file3.bmp'
```

#### Combining all the images into one numpy array

To combine all the images into one array:

```
x = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in filelist])
```

#### Pickling a numpy array

To save a numpy array to file using pickle:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump( x, filehandle, protocol=2 )
```

where   `x` is the numpy array to be save, `filehandle` is the handle for the pickle file, such as `open('filename.p', 'wb')`, and `protocol=2` tells pickle to use its current format rather than some ancient out-of-date format.

Alternatively, numpy arrays can be pickled using methods supplied by numpy (hat tip: [tegan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4174485/tegan)).  To dump array `x` in file `file.npy`, use:

```
x.dump('file.npy')
```

To load array `x` back in from file:

```
x = np.load('file.npy')
```

For more information, see the numpy docs for [dump](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dump.html) and [load](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.load.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot . It worked . Another question if you don't mind can i load this numpy array into pickle ?

Comment: Yes, numpy arrays work with pickle: `pickle.dump( x, filehandle, protocol=2 )`

Comment: What are the parameters ?

Comment: `x` is the numpy array (as shown in the answer, for example).  `filehandle` is the handle for the pickle file, such as `open('filename.p', 'wb')`.  `protocol=2` just tells pickle to use its current format rather than some ancient out-of-date format.

Comment: Brother i can't thank you enough. You saved hours of mine . Thank you very much for your help. Regards

Comment: @John1024 The syntax you use that looks like `[<expression> for <var> in <list>]` to me is not one I can find a reference to so I can see what the precise syntax is. Can you provide one? Looks like handy syntax to know.

Comment: @omatai Yes, it is very useful.  It is called _list comprehension_.  As I don't have any favorite tutorials on the subject, I'll offer [this link](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+list+comprehension) which will lead you to lots of information.

Comment: You don't have to import pickle to save numpy arrays; numpy can do this by itself (I think it uses pickle anyway, but saves you an import / worrying about protocols): `myarray.dump("good_filename.npy")` This lets you do the entire thing in one line, if you like: `np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in filelist]).dump("good_filename.npy")`

Comment: @tegan Very nice!  Thanks.  Answer updated with info on `numpy.ndarray.dump` and `numpy.load`.

Answer (score 6):

Use OpenCV's [imread()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html?highlight=imread#cv2.imread) function together with [os.listdir()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm), like

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

instances = []

# Load in the images
for filepath in os.listdir('images/'):
    instances.append(cv2.imread('images/{0}'.format(filepath),0))

print(type(instances[0]))
```

> class 'numpy.ndarray'

This returns you a list (==`instances`) in which all the greyscale values of the images are stored. For colour images simply set `.format(filepath),1`.

Answer (score 0):

I just would like to share two sites where one can split a dataset into train, test and validation sets: [split_folder](https://pypi.org/project/split-folders/#description)
and create numpy arrays out of images residing in respective folders [code snippet from medium](https://medium.com/@muskulpesent/create-numpy-array-of-images-fecb4e514c4b)  by **muskulpesent**