# loading images from mnist into a numpy array

Tags: python

I have downloaded the MNIST files from:

http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/index.html

because I want to train an SVM like the following:

```
clf_svm = LinearSVC()
clf_svm.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

but I see that the data that I downloaded is divided in training images and labels, so how can I join them to form a numpy array that comprises the X_train variable.

I have tried to do the following:

```
path_train="D:\\Anaconda\\t10k-images-idx3-ubyte\\t10k-images.idx3-ubyte"
f=open(path_train,"rb")
train_data=cPickle.load(f)
```

but I got the following error:

```
train_data=cPickle.load(f)

EOFError
```

so the question is how to form that X_train with the information that I need?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195113/how-to-load-multiple-images-in-a-numpy-array
Please refer to this link for solution

Comment: I think you should use `train_data=cPickle.load(f)`.