# How can extract an image dataset using Neural Network?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, export-to-csv

I am sorry for this type of questions! I searched a lot on google and youtube but i am failed to get the accurate knowledge for extracting an image dataset in a single time.
And after images extraction **How should I save it as csv file?**

Step by step it will be:

1. Extract the images Dataset
2. Save as CSV file

I prefer to extract image Dataset using **Keras API module**. But I am confused which module will be perfect to use and how should extract? I don't know!

Comment: Are you asking how to create a dataset for a specific task? if thats it, you need to refer to the documentations for your specific framework you use.

Comment: I haved Dataset as images. But I could not extract it . After extract it i can use Logistics regression for predict accuracy.

Comment: You can load the images and convert them into numpy arrays. I would highly suggest saving those images as numpy arrays rather to csv file. Then use those numpy array to train your model. https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/importing-image-data-into-numpy-arrays

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I wrote haved. It will be have !

Comment: @ Bahroze Ali , How can do it together. I mean how can I should do all of the images in a single time !

Comment: I guess you should consolut Keras/TF API/documentation. maybe this comes handy to you [Link](https://www.dlology.com/blog/an-easy-guide-to-build-new-tensorflow-datasets-and-estimator-with-keras-model/)

Comment: @ImdadulHaque I got an idea. You can load images one by one , convert them into numpy array and then append it to another numpy array. You can use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195113/how-to-load-multiple-images-in-a-numpy-array

Comment: @ Bahroze Ali  I am sorry, it is not the solution what i wanted. Because i have more than 3k images data. I want to do it in a single operation. But thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

- That can be possible with some basic file handling and using libraries.
- Check the following link, where images are loaded and saved as pickle files to be used in a neural network. These pickle files can be saved and loaded using a [library pickle](https://pythonprogramming.net/loading-custom-data-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/).
- An image is stored as a numpy array which can be converted to csv. Check out the following [link](https://pythonprogramming.net/loading-custom-data-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/) for this task.